# How can we make it infinite scrollable?

Tags: jquery, css

I came through a `Codepen` here where this cool menu is displayed.
I tried my best to customize it but i was not able to make it infinitely scrollable.  ( When I scroll, the menu loops)
here is the pen

> https://codepen.io/dev_loop/pen/PoZBOBx
> Could you please help me.
> Thanks.

Demo of an Infinite Scroll Menu
[Demo](https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ScrollLoopMenu/)

Comment: what do you mean by infinitely scrollable?

Comment: @Frenchy when i scroll the menu loops..

Comment: its not again clear..when you are in top of menu what do you do? go to bottom?

Comment: @Frenchy see the question again, i've added the demo

Comment: I vote for Weronika Irvin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

so i wanted to see the possibility of locomotiveScroll, and in same time i have found a quick solution to your problem:

i have addded some lines in your scss: this lines reset the counter to 1

```
.resetcounter::before{
    counter-set: menucounter 1 ;
}
```

[Solution Here: Infinite Scrolling](https://codepen.io/Frenchy62620/pen/poNVaEN)

**How the program is functional?**

The logic i add a `data-scroll-call="id"` spy at element of middle of all menuitems (5nth here)

when the scroll down sees a spy (`data-scroll-call="0" for example`), its add new items (`clone jQuery`) to the container and increment id and  i update the locomotiveScroll , and so on.

when the scroll up sees a spy, the program deletes all items of `data-scroll-call with id + 2`

The difficulty was to filter the messages which pollutes the `event call` whe n locomotiveScroll was updated to take new item spy

Comment: its analysis, you have to rebuild your html each time you are in the bottom if you want infinite loop..so you have to clone the different items to appears when you arrive in the zone..if you havent developp the program you show, it will be difficult for you to modify it... Its another logic of program

Comment: @Ben i have found a solution for your problem

Comment: @Frenchy could you please make a codepen of it.. thanks

Comment: @Frenchy that is awesome but there seems some margin or pading between the beginning of the second loop (begining of the list). Can u fix that?

Comment: i have just added `<p><br><br><br><br><br></p>` at the end of last item   to make the separation visible..but you could put off

Comment: @Frenchy that was great. Thanks a lot.

Comment: it was interesting...glad to help you and i have learnt something about locomotiveScroll

Comment: I will contact you if i need more help. thanks again!

Comment: i hope you have understood the logic of my programmation, its most essential